# "relation-symbols" tag proposal

Tags: discussion, tagging

Currently we have over a hundred questions tagged both [mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathmode) and [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols), and of the newest 15 questions, 6 concern mathematical relations.

Looking over those 6 questions, I see one at least, [Symbol about not orthogonality in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27651/symbol-about-not-orthogonality-in-latex), where the title would be more immediately comprehensible to me if it had been tagged something like [relation-symbols].  Likewise, I recall looking for the question [How to typeset $:=$ correctly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/how-to-typseset-correctly) not long ago and failing to find it, only finding it when it was referred to in a question asked since then.

I propose to create this tag, unless a better name is found, and add the tag to the ten most-viewed questions that fit it.  Perhaps tags for other classes of maths symbols would also be appropriate.

Comment: Retagging! ;-) `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If [relation-symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relation-symbols) would indeed encompass a dozen or even more questions, I'm all for creating this tag. However (and just in case this wasn't implied in Charles' proposal), the more general [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols) tag should *not* be removed from questions newly tagged with [relation-symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relation-symbols).

Comment: I've looked back and found what I would classify as the 12th newest such question from February.  Of course the symbols tag should remain: in general the bigger tags are more important than the rarer tags.

Comment: @Charles: I'd say just start retagging -- and don't flood the front page. ;-)

Comment: I've put the most recent five through: batches of five are carefully calibrated to annoy but not to flood.